# Is there a way of blocking some Facebook app permissions?

Tags: facebook, permissions

Is it possible to add a Facebook application but deny it one or some of the permissions it asks for, such as posting on your wall/timeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible but not via Facebook UI.

You can use one of these Google Chrome extensions

- [fPrivacy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lkllliihmodekgjcioihaaodkbpeleph)
- [FBSecure](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mlnhcepfaddcopbeggpobodmmodilgmc)

Note that blocking some of the application permissions may result in the application losing some of its main functionality.

Comment: Actually, you can do it via Facebook UI.

Comment: For some settings, not all. Some show as *Required* @dnbrv

Comment: If an app requires posting permissions, run away from it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it via Facebook's regular UI. Simply go to [App Privacy Settings](http://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications) and click `Edit` next to the app, from which you want to take away posting permissions. Then click `Remove` next to the permission you want to revoke. You can also change privacy setting for the posts there.